# Help identify set - Star Wars Episode 1-3 Era

Tags: star-wars

Been organizing old toys and ran into this completely built part that looks like some backdrop item from Tatooine - a vertical thing you see near Luke's farm. It looks very familiar, and I can swear I saw it on one of the boxes along some other, main thing.
[image]

For reference, the same box had a Gionossian fighter from Episode 2 and Darth Vader's ship from Force Unleashed series. Images of those below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These parts are from

[4488: Millennium Falcon](https://brickset.com/sets/4488-1/Millennium-Falcon)

this set contains additional parts to build a Y-wing Fighter when also using additional parts from sets 4489, 4490 and 4491.

[image]

Comment: That's a great find! I think it might be from set 4491 though, since I also found a bunch of loose brown block that fit the picture. Thank you!